# How to Filter Object Fields by a String Array

Tags: arrays, object, filter

How can I filter an Object's field by an string array?

eg.

```
catValues:{
    "1":{
        value:10,
        code:5
     },
    "3":{
        value:10,
        code:5
     },
    "5":{
        value:10,
        code:5
     }
}


var chosenCats = ["1","5"]

result: {"1":{value:10, code:5}, "5":{value:10, code:5}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a new object and insert just the chosen cat values.

```
var chosenCatValues = {};

for (var cat of chosenCats) {
  chosenCatValues[cat] = catValues[cat];
}
```

Or you can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
var chosenCatValues = Object.keys(catValues)
  .filter(key => chosenCats.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = catValues[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var catValues = {
  "1": {
    value: 10,
    code: 5
  },
  "3": {
    value: 10,
    code: 5
  },
  "5": {
    value: 10,
    code: 5
  }
};

var chosenCats = ["1", "5"];

var chosenCatValues = Object.keys(catValues)
  .filter(key => chosenCats.includes(key))
  .reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = catValues[key];
    return obj;
  }, {});

console.log(chosenCatValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Note: This will work with array of strings as well considering they are numbers.**

```js
var catValues = {
    "1":{
        value:10,
        code:5
     },
    "3":{
        value:10,
        code:5
     },
    "5":{
        value:10,
        code:5
     }
}

var chosen = ['1','5'];

const func = (chosen, catValues) => {
    var ch = {};
    chosen.map(chose => {
      if(chose in catValues) {
        ch[chose] = catValues[chose]
      }
  })
  return ch
}

console.log(func(chosen, catValues))
```